# CSS: Animating a different colored circle from the center of a button on click

Tags: css, reactjs, css-animations, styled-components

I have a button which I'd like to animate when it is clicked (ideally it would change the state to the second color permanently). While I experimented with a background-image/liner-gradient solution, it did not achieve my desired circle effect and did not persist.

Using [this CodePen](https://codepen.io/MarsAndBack/pen/ZwPMvM) as inspiration, I figured I'd try to animate the circle using the ::before pseudoselector.

```
const ClickAnimation = keyframes`
  from {
    transform: scale(0);
    opacity: 1;
  }

  to {
    transform: scale(1);
    opacity: 1;
  }
`;

const StyledButton = styled.button`
  color: white;
  background-color: ${colors.secondary500};
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;

  &:hover {
    background-color: ${colors.secondary400};
  }

  &::before {
    content: "";
    background-color: ${colors.secondary300};
  }

  &:active::before {
    animation: ${ClickAnimation} 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.250, 0.460, 0.450, 0.940) both;
  }

  &:disabled {
    background-color: ${colors.primary300};
  }
`

const LargeButton = styled(StyledButton)`
  width: 100%;
  line-height: 23px;
  font-size: 19px;
  font-weight: 600;
  padding: 8px 0;
  border-radius: 4px;
`

const SmallButton = styled(StyledButton)`
  height: 28px;
  width: 148px;
  border-radius: 16px;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: 500;
  line-height: 18px;
`

export default Button;
```

While my hover effect is working, I'm not actually getting any animation on click (:active) at the moment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The opacity is still 1 at the end of the animation in **ClickAnimation**. Shouldn't it be 0?

Comment: But the element that is getting the opacity is the one I want to appear at the end of the click. I'm setting the animation on the pseudo-element at the moment. I tried switching it to 0, but it was the same result.

Comment: Ah ok, my bad. Didn't see that you are changing the scale at first. 
In that case you can do this. [Here's the codepen](https://codepen.io/kasunwijeratne/pen/rEbbpV)
So the catch is you have to set width and height initially (plus other positioning properties mentioned in codepen) for CSS to know which extent it should transform to.

Comment: Thanks! This is definitely helping animation the ::before element, but I'm still struggling with a couple things. I'd like the circle to come directly from the center of my button element and I don't want it to overflow the button. Right now the circle acts independently of the button, but I'd like it to only show up within the boundaries of the button. Here's the pen that shows what I have so far: https://codepen.io/ipenguin67/pen/orremB

Comment: [Updated codepne](https://codepen.io/kasunwijeratne/pen/gNNJWj)
I have setup the animation in percentage rather than using from/to so we can complete the animation before active state changes.

Comment: Go through the code and let me know if you need further clarification.